# What is the y_pred and y_true when calculating loss in a multi output keras model?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I currently have a multi output model

```
model=Model(inputs=x1, outputs=[y1,y2])
model.compile((optimizer='sgd', loss=[cutom_loss,'mse'])
```

What is the `y_pred` and `y_true` values here for `mse` loss function? What is the `y_true` for `mse`; is it output of y2 alone or its both y1 and y2?

In my `custom_loss` I need to pass y_true and y_pred from both the outputs  sepeartaly for calculation

```
 def custom_loss(y1_true, y1_pred,y2_true, y2_pred):
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot define a 'global' loss function.
[A loss function is always computed only on one output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172165/keras-multiple-output-custom-loss-function) (see the pseudo-code in the accepted answer).

In your example the custom loss will be computed on y1_true and y1_pred, while the mse will be computed on y2_true and y2_pred.

If you want a custom loss that includes both y1 and y2 outputs, I can think of two ways:

1. Collapse multiple outputs in one output: if y1 and y2 are similar vectors, you could concatenate them in order to have only one output. Then in your custom loss you apply some indexing/slicing in order to separate the two outputs.
2. Make the loss an output of your model: create a custom network graph
   (using keras functional API and the backend) that computes the loss,
   by taking y1_true and y2_true as an input to the network; by doing
   that, your final model will have 3 outputs; y1_pred, y2_pred and the
   loss. After the training you can discard the part of the model your
   are not interested anymore (y_true inputs and loss output).

I remember that I had a similar problem in the past and I chose to implement option 2, but it was kind of a pain.